# jQuery class selector click() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use a class selector (".user") button to run another function. However, no functions will run when I click the button. Below is the code I am working on, with the class button at the very bottom. I just can't figure out why it is not working. I know my getNewTweets function works and I have another button that runs that properly, but the class selector does not work. Could anyone tell me why?

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var $body = $('body');
    var $timeline = $('<div class="timeline"></div>');
    var $btn = $('<input/>').attr({type:'button',name:'getNewTweets',value:'Get New Tweets'})

    $body.html('');
    $timeline.html('');
    $btn.appendTo($body);
    $timeline.appendTo($body);

    var currentIndex = 0; //Current index of tweets shown

    function getNewTweets() {

      var index = streams.home.length - 1 - currentIndex;

      while(index >= 0) {
          var tweet = streams.home[index];
          var $tweet = $('<div class="tweet"></div>');
          var $time = $('<div class="time"></div>');
          var $message = $('<div class="message"></div>')
          var $user = $('<button class=user></button>');
          $time.text(tweet.created_at);
          $user.text('@' + tweet.user);
          $message.text('tweetled: ' + tweet.message);
          $tweet.append($user);
          $message.appendTo($tweet);
          $time.appendTo($tweet);
          $tweet.appendTo($timeline);
          index -= 1;
          currentIndex += 1;
      }
    };

    $btn.click(getNewTweets);

    $(".user").click(getNewTweets);
```

Answer (score 1):

The buttons with `user` class is dynamically added in to the DOM, so by the time `$(".user").click(getNewTweets);` is executed, `.user` might not be available which leads to no click event listener attached. The solution is to attach event listener on document instead `$(document).on('click', '.user', getNewTweets);`